# Mirror two software RAID volumes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid

I have two software RAID volumes of differing speed and reliability on Ubuntu 12.10. I want to mirror the contents of the faster, but less reliable `/dev/md0` to `/dev/md1`.

My plan was to build a composite RAID1 volume on top of `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1` using mdadm, but I'm having trouble building the volume.

mdam warns that the individual component arrays appear to be part of an existing array, and after reboot the kenel states that the array is degraded and is in need of repair.

Is it possible to build a composite array of two existing software arrays? If not, is there some solution other than rsync that I'm overlooking? Bonus points if I can make the OS have a read preference for the faster `/dev/md0`.

**command used to create arrays:**

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 -c256 --raid-devices=4 /dev/xvdb /dev/xvdc /dev/xvdd /dev/xvde
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=10 -c256 --raid-devices=4 /dev/xvdf /dev/xvdg /dev/xvdh /dev/xvdi
mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=1 -c256 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/md1
```

**mdadm.conf:**

```
DEVICE /dev/xvdb /dev/xvdc /dev/xvdd /dev/xvde
DEVICE /dev/xvdf /dev/xvdg /dev/xvdh /dev/xvdi
DEVICE /dev/md0 /dev/md1
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=dn1-c.foo.com:0 UUID=b6bf6a3f:09e60e75:a04ce9d6:8a668b84
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=dn1-c.foo.com:1 UUID=d02217aa:4188e959:2a5d07e9:28e0d724
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=dn1-c.foo.com:2 UUID=c5266085:2adcbd6d:de4a8335:87e255d6
```

**relevent dmesg output:**

```
[7333496.257635] md: bind<xvdd>
[7333496.262758] md: bind<xvdh>
[7333496.266326] md: bind<xvdc>
[7333496.270206] md: bind<xvdf>
[7333496.274588] md: bind<xvdb>
[7333496.279373] md: bind<xvdg>
[7333496.286136] md: bind<xvde>
[7333496.290990] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
[7333496.291006] md/raid0:md127: md_size is 3522926592 sectors.
[7333496.291012] md: RAID0 configuration for md127 - 1 zone
[7333496.291017] md: zone0=[xvdb/xvdc/xvdd/xvde]
[7333496.291026]       zone-offset=         0KB, device-offset=         0KB, size=1761463296KB
[7333496.291033] 
[7333496.291048] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 1803738415104
[7333496.291154] md: bind<xvdi>
[7333496.294186]  md127: unknown partition table
[7333496.296463] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
[7333496.296830] md/raid10:md126: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
[7333496.296839] md/raid10:md126: active with 4 out of 4 devices
[7333496.296869] md126: detected capacity change from 0 to 2198754295808
[7333496.308765] raid6: int64x1   1748 MB/s
[7333496.314083]  md126: unknown partition table
[7333496.376772] raid6: int64x2   2369 MB/s
[7333496.444782] raid6: int64x4   1634 MB/s
[7333496.512757] raid6: int64x8   1673 MB/s
[7333496.580754] raid6: sse2x1    4746 MB/s
[7333496.648749] raid6: sse2x2    5793 MB/s
[7333496.716755] raid6: sse2x4    6073 MB/s
[7333496.716766] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (6073 MB/s)
[7333496.717708] xor: automatically using best checksumming function: generic_sse
[7333496.736747]    generic_sse:  2205.000 MB/sec
[7333496.736755] xor: using function: generic_sse (2205.000 MB/sec)
[7333496.738128] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[7333496.738138] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[7333496.738146] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
```

**contents of /dev:**

```
root@dn1-c:/home/ubuntu# ls /dev/md*
/dev/md126  /dev/md127

/dev/md:
dn1-c.foo.com:0  dn1-c.foo.com:1
root@dn1-c:/home/ubuntu#
```

**mdadm -D output**

```
root@dn1-c:/home/ubuntu# mdadm -D /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Mar 13 16:29:17 2013
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 2147220992 (2047.75 GiB 2198.75 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1073610496 (1023.87 GiB 1099.38 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Mar 13 17:56:48 2013
          State : clean, resyncing (PENDING) 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 256K

           Name : dn1-c.foo.com:1  (local to host dn1-c.foo.com)
           UUID : d02217aa:4188e959:2a5d07e9:28e0d724
         Events : 5

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     202       80        0      active sync   /dev/xvdf
       1     202       96        1      active sync   /dev/xvdg
       2     202      112        2      active sync   /dev/xvdh
       3     202      128        3      active sync   /dev/xvdi
root@dn1-c:/home/ubuntu# mdadm -D /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Mar 13 16:28:23 2013
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 1761463296 (1679.86 GiB 1803.74 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Mar 13 16:28:23 2013
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 256K

           Name : dn1-c.foo.com:0  (local to host dn1-c.foo.com)
           UUID : b6bf6a3f:09e60e75:a04ce9d6:8a668b84
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     202       16        0      active sync   /dev/xvdb
       1     202       32        1      active sync   /dev/xvdc
       2     202       48        2      active sync   /dev/xvdd
       3     202       64        3      active sync   /dev/xvde
```

Comment: Do not cross-post on multiple [SE] sites. If you feel your question would be better answered on a different site, Flag it for migration. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  It sounds like you directed `mdadm` to the individual disks instead of the array, but since you didn't specify the exact command, or the output of `mdadm -D`, it's hard to know where you went wrong.

Comment: Added tons of extra data, hope that helps.